# Linking paginated articles to sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My google fu is currently letting me down so I thought I'd ask here for some help..

I have a page that has a single article on it (url.com/article/article-headline). When you scroll down the page using jQuery it loads the next article and changes the url (url.com/article/next-article-headline).

My issue is, I have a left hand sidebar which has a list of all the articles. What I'd like to happen is to have the current article highlighted. So when you scroll down the page and the next article loads the next sidebar article title is highlighted etc etc.

If you need an example of what I mean you can see it in action on time.com
http://time.com/4010146/smartphones-dinner/ (scroll down the page and watch the URL and sidebar)

I'm really struggling to find what it's called in order to do a proper search. I guess it's something similar to scrollspy but I'm not sure. Are there any plugins that exist for this?

Comment: post some code and a fiddle

Comment: Are you using AJAX to get the next article? Please post the code that retrieves the next article.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data-attributes to your sidebar and the article section at the main content. With the help of which you could determine the article title.

Using jQuery then add a class named "active" which would determine the current article is active and style the "active" class later just for the sidebar.

Example: `.sidebar-article.active { color: #f00; }`

IF you need a solution you need to also provide appropriate HTML structure and jQuery code with the help of fiddle. So that rest of the code snippet we could provide and also not harm your current code base.

Comment: This is a good starting point thanks. I'll see how I get on and if I get stuck I'll drop in some code